# create list of nearby users using python

Tags: python, distance, nested-loops

I have a list of users with latitude and longitude values for each. I'm trying to create a list of "nearby users" for each user. I believe my distance calculation is working, however I'm stuck creating the list for each user.

```
users = [

{'email':'austin1@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.3, 'long': -97.67, 'nearby_users': []},
{'email':'austin2@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.2, 'long': -97.73,'nearby_users': []},
{'email':'austin3@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.26, 'long': -97.74,'nearby_users': []},
{'email':'palm_beach@gmail.com', 'lat': 26.62, 'long': -80.05, 'nearby_users': []}
]

radius = 1

def compare_users(user_a, user_b):

a_email = user_a['email']
a_lat = float(user_a['lat'])
a_long = float(user_a['long'])
a_nearby_users = user_a['nearby_users']

b_email = user_b['email']
b_lat = float(user_b['lat'])
b_long = float(user_b['long'])
b_nearby_users = user_b['nearby_users']

if b_lat > (a_lat - radius):
    if b_lat < (a_lat + radius):
        if b_long > (a_long - radius):
            if b_long < (a_long + radius):

                b_nearby_users.append(a_email)

for user_a in range(len(users)):
    for user_b in range(user_a + 1, len(users)):
        compare_users(users[user_a], users[user_b])
```

I'm expecting to see reciprocal nearby users and that is not happening in a logical way. Here are the results I'm receiving:

```
[{'email': 'austin1@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.3, 'long': -97.67, 'nearby_users': []},
{'email': 'austin2@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.2, 'long': -97.73, 'nearby_users': ['austin1@gmail.com']},
{'email': 'austin3@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.26, 'long': -97.74, 'nearby_users': ['austin1@gmail.com', 'austin2@gmail.com']},
{'email': 'palm_beach@gmail.com', 'lat': 26.62, 'long': -80.05, 'nearby_users': []}]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you just need to add `a_nearby_users.append(b_email)` right above your line `b_nearby_users.append(a_email)`? Perhaps it is only going one direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added the following as my comment suggested I *think* the result was correct:

```
users = [

{'email':'austin1@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.3, 'long': -97.67, 'nearby_users': []},
{'email':'austin2@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.2, 'long': -97.73,'nearby_users': []},
{'email':'austin3@gmail.com', 'lat': 30.26, 'long': -97.74,'nearby_users': []},
{'email':'palm_beach@gmail.com', 'lat': 26.62, 'long': -80.05, 'nearby_users': []}
]

radius = 1

def compare_users(user_a, user_b):

    a_email = user_a['email']
    a_lat = float(user_a['lat'])
    a_long = float(user_a['long'])
    a_nearby_users = user_a['nearby_users']

    b_email = user_b['email']
    b_lat = float(user_b['lat'])
    b_long = float(user_b['long'])
    b_nearby_users = user_b['nearby_users']

    if b_lat > (a_lat - radius):
        if b_lat < (a_lat + radius):
            if b_long > (a_long - radius):
                if b_long < (a_long + radius):
                    a_nearby_users.append(b_email)
                    b_nearby_users.append(a_email)

for user_a in range(len(users)):
    for user_b in range(user_a + 1, len(users)):
        compare_users(users[user_a], users[user_b])
print(users)
```

Outputs:

> [{'nearby_users': ['austin2@gmail.com', 'austin3@gmail.com'], 'lat': 30.3, 'email': 'austin1@gmail.com', 'long': -97.67}, {'nearby_users': ['austin1@gmail.com', 'austin3@gmail.com'], 'lat': 30.2, 'email': 'austin2@gmail.com', 'long': -97.73}, {'nearby_users': ['austin1@gmail.com', 'austin2@gmail.com'], 'lat': 30.26, 'email': 'austin3@gmail.com', 'long': -97.74}, {'nearby_users': [], 'lat': 26.62, 'email': 'palm_beach@gmail.com', 'long': -80.05}]

Comment: Yes! For some reason I thought that would create duplicates. That's it! Thank you.